# What's the lifespan of Deuterium and Helium-3 in the Sun?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, sun, stars, fusion

What's the lifespan of Deuterium and Helium-3 in the sun?
How long on average, the Deuterium and Helium-3 atoms last in the Sun's core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the current version of [Wikipedia’s article on the proton-proton chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain), typical lifetimes are

- protons: $10^{10}$ years (i.e. the lifetime of the Sun)
- deuterons: about one second
- helium-3: about 400 years